# Get parent process status in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, parent-child, status

Trying to get the process status of a given process P from one of its childs P'.

I know about the function waitpid(), but in the doc, it said that it's used to check the status of a child process.

So is there any other way to ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, `waitpid()` is documented to fail with `ECHILD` if the specified pid identifies a process that is not a child of the calling process.  I guess there's an off chance that the OP's implementation is buggy in that regard, but if it were then I certainly would not recommend relying on such a bug.

Comment: If a child's parent process dies, the orphaned child will be re-homed to `init`. This could be used to detect in the child the parent is no longer there. At this point in time, any information about the former parent process is long gone, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard function by which a process can wait for its parent to terminate or obtain its parent's exit status.  The process tree just doesn't work that way -- children notify their parents when they exit, not the other way around.

Therefore, if you want child processes to learn of their parents' demise, you must arrange for the parent to actively notify them.  This seems like a job for signaling.  If you need only to inform children that the parent exited cleanly (i.e. by returning from `main()` or calling `exit()`) then that's probably enough by itself.  Choose a signal -- maybe `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` -- and have the parent register an `atexit()` handler that sends that signal to the children.  That might or might not require the parent to keep track of its children.

Inasmuch as you mention getting the parent's exit status, however, you probably want a bit more.  You can get coarse-grained information to the children by choosing which of two (or more) signals to send to them, but for more detailed information you need an IPC mechanism.  You might write an exit status to shared memory or to a pipe (or to several of them), send a message to a socket or message queue, write a status to an ordinary file, or perhaps something else I haven't thought of.

You should also consider that the existing model works pretty well, and has done for 40-ish years.  It may indeed not meet your needs, but I urge you to think about whether the design you have in mind could be improved to fit more cleanly into the Unix model.

Comment: Note that the functions registered with `atexit()` will only be called if the program stops under control and not by calling one of the fast exit functions.

Comment: That is a good observation, @JonathanLeffler, which I somewhat pushed under the rug.  I did stipulate that the approach described supposes that the parent process terminates by calling `exit()` or returning from `main()`; if it terminates in some other way then it would need to explicitly run the child-notifying machinery before doing so for the children to hear about it.  That cannot be relied upon to happen in all cases -- in particular, it will not happen if the parent dies as a result of receiving a `SIGKILL`.